# Fetching Log Analytics Primary Key

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

I was trying to get the Azure Log Analytics Workspace primary key by using this command:

```
Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey -ResourceGroupName "abc-rg" -Name "abc-LAW"
```

The above command outputs both primary & secondary keys. But how can I just get the primary key to a variable and use it in my PowerShell code?

I was trying this line to get the FIRST key:

```
(Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey -ResourceGroupName aby-rg -Name abys-LAW).value[0]
```

but I get an error:

> Cannot index into a null array.
> At line:36 char:1
>
> - [string]$omsSharedKey = (Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey  ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
>   ```

Thanks,

Comment: OK Guys, found a way.
It wshould be,
(Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey -ResourceGroupName aby-rg -Name abys-LAW). PrimarySharedKey

Comment: Hi @av-az-2020 Since you have solved the issue by yourself, could you please post your answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the **Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey** cmdlet is an object of type [PSWorkspaceKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.operationalinsights.models.psworkspacekeys?view=azurerm-ps), with two properties:

- PrimarySharedKey
- SecondarySharedKey

So you should be able to get to the PrimarySharedKey with `$keys.PrimarySharedKey`.

When in doubt, you can use the `GetType` method on the object to know its type and `Get-Member` cmdlet to view the complete listing of its members.

```sh
PS C:\> $keys = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroup> -Name <WorkspaceName>
PS C:\> $keys

PrimarySharedKey   : 5LLi6guNfYKJ0ipSY9cv0NJ8ZeOAHlz7dX0hI9S5RTI6ISnGwa3aTvq/Mzg2SlwaaRqkZAAaSiYStlpx48y8zQ==
SecondarySharedKey : YAQo85BdaEc+W7GD2BCmXbvMFtS9XkMYui6pECl6dZS9rqk7gZjy5wo7s0/Tk+Ceq9zaNW9bbggSUaYzpeUrXw==

PS C:\> $keys.PrimarySharedKey
5LLi6guNfYKJ0ipSY9cv0NJ8ZeOAHlz7dX0hI9S5RTI6ISnGwa3aTvq/Mzg2SlwaaRqkZAAaSiYStlpx48y8zQ==

PS C:\> $keys.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSWorkspaceKeys                          System.Object

PS C:\> $keys | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

   TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.OperationalInsights.Models.PSWorkspaceKeys

Name               MemberType Definition
----               ---------- ----------
PrimarySharedKey   Property   string PrimarySharedKey {get;set;}
SecondarySharedKey Property   string SecondarySharedKey {get;set;}
```

Reference: [Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/get-azoperationalinsightsworkspacesharedkey?view=azps-5.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Fetching Log Analytics workspace primary key using azure cli

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace get-shared-keys --resource-group $ResourceGroup --workspace-name $loganalyticsname --query "primarySharedKey"
```

Reference [Azure Documentation](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/monitor/log-analytics/workspace?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-workspace-get-shared-keys)